# How to make PHPUnit wait for condition test?

Tags: php, if-statement, phpunit, tdd, file-exists

Every-time that run the test it fails at first run and pass at second run.

Here is the code:

```
 /** @test */
    public function some_function_test()
        {
            $file = file_exists($this->path.'file');

            if ($file) {
                echo "\n file exists! \n";
            }else{
                $this->createFile;
            }

         $this->assertEquals($file, true);

        }
```

when I delete the file and run the test again it fails.
which tells me that the assertion is running before my if statement.

if the assertion is running first, can I make it wait for my condition test?

Comment: `Assertion` cannot run before `if`. If you don't have a file - you create it with `createFile`, is it a method btw? Then it should be `createFile()`, but `$file` variable does not change in `else` branch. That's why your test fails.

Comment: @u_mulder But it doesn't matter if  $file didn't change because it has a full path and file name!  the Assertion should return true if file exist! but it seems me that Assertion check before even file is created. and why if I run a second time the test always pass?

Comment: Because second time you run the test file is __created__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion will **never** run before `if`.

Your test fails because in `else` branch you don't change `$file` after file is created with `createFile`, so in `else` branch `$file` is still `false`. I suppose you need to change `$file` to `true`:

```
public function some_function_test()
{
    $file = file_exists($this->path.'file');

    if ($file) {
        echo "\n file exists! \n";
    }else{
        $this->createFile();    // you're calling a method, aren't you?
        $file = true;
    }

    $this->assertEquals($file, true);
    // or simplier:
    // $this->assertTrue($file);
}
```

Comment: yes I called a method right after else statement but as soon as this method created the file the Assertion should see that and return true!  or is there something that I'm not catching. is else statement changing the $file to false? if so how?

Comment: Do you understand that assertion checks __value of variable__? It checks value of variable `$file`. If file does not exist value of `$file` is __false__. When you create your file - you just create your file, you don't change value of `$file`. So it is still __false__. Is it clear?

Comment: *"is else statement changing the $file to false?"* -- the `else` branch is executed **because** `$file` is `false`.

Comment: @u_mulder thank you it all working fine now. I'm still new to programming specially TDD. You rocker!